# Rails / Paranoia Gem: Undefined local variable or method `acts_as_paranoid'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, acts-as-paranoid

**Environment:**

- gem "paranoia", "~> 2.0" (https://github.com/radar/paranoia);
- rails 4.1.8;
- sqlite3;

When I did `Listing.find(1)` in rails console, it sends me such error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_paranoid' for Listing (call 'Listing.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

If I remove the `acts_as_paranoid` in Listing model, the query can go through.

Other than in the Rails console, the Paranoia gem itself works well.

Did anyone meet this issue before?

Comment: Did you restart the server and console?

Comment: Yes, I did restart both server and console.

Comment: Don't know why, but after I restarted the iTerm, the rails console can work.